# SQL database error exception in c# using VS 2019 edition

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am new to C# database and I have been battling with this error for a few hours.
When I created the table, I used *ctrl + s* to save it but it saved like normal saving into *My Documents* which I think the problem comes from that.
[image: This is the error I am getting]

[image: This is the table I created]

Comment: `SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Table]`?

Comment: You don't want to select from the database but from a table.

Comment: How do I save the table since ctrl + s is saving it has document @pensum

Comment: The document you are saving is just the queries you wrote in a file.sql but when you ran the code, it did execute in your application because I can see you can update the table now.

Comment: Your error is that you are trying to select * from a database. You want to select * from a table in a database.  Lukasz comment is giving you the answer.

Comment: @pensum Yes... you are right but how do I save table?

Comment: You almost certainly do not want to name your `Table` table.

Comment: You should see it in MSSQLLocalDB that you have named. When you execute the queries, you don't need to save. It updated the database already.

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp how will I save table? If i use ctrl + s, it is saving has .ql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Table]`

You have to place your your table name in the place of table as mentioned below.

`SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Customer]`

**Then do this:**

In the upper-left corner of Table Designer, select Update.

In the Preview Database Updates dialog box, select Update Database.

The Customers table is created in the local database file.